# How to convert URL to NSImage (Swift 3)

Tags: swift, macos, url, swift3, nsimage

I need to create an NSImage from a url. I want to be able to use it in my Mac application.

[image]

Please Help!!

Comment: use nsimage init with data

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
let image = NSImage(data: Data(contentsOf: url))
```

Comment: This will block the main thread and make your app very unresponsive.

Comment: you can always use background thread for this, if it becomes unresponsive

Answer (score 4):

In Swift 4.2, we can already use:
`let image: NSImage = NSImage(contentsOf: url!)!`

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5 and safely unwrap

```
do {
    if let url = URL(string: imageURL) {
        let imageData = try Data(contentsOf: url)
        let image = NSImage(data: imageData)
    }
} catch {
    // Handle the error
}
```